# Number of Divisors

Tags: math, division

How to find the Number of divisors of a number 'n' that are also divisible by another number 'k' without looping through all the divisors of n?
I tried the following:

Stored powers of all prime factors of n in an associative array A and did similarly for k, stored the powers of all primes factors in array B.

```
    ans = 1
    for a in A:    // Here a is the prime factor and A[a] gives its power
        ans *= if( a is present in B ) ? 1 : A[a] + 1
    print ans
```

Note : It is not homework.

Comment: If this is homework you should add the tag. Also tell us what you have tried already

Comment: Why are you multiplying `ans` by the power + 1?

Comment: And do you want the number of divisors or their product? In your question, you said you want the number, but the fact that you're multiplying to build up your answer makes me think you might want their product.

Comment: Generally to get number of divisors, we need to multiply the (1+powers) of all its prime factors.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought you were going for all of its prime divisors.

Comment: Why -1 for my question??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the number of divisors of `n` that are divisible by `k`:

- if `k` is not a divisor of `n`, the number is 0,
- otherwise, it's the number of divisors of `n/k`.

If `d` is a divisor of `n` that is divisible by `k`, then `d/k` is a divisor of `n/k`. Conversely, if `e` is a divisor of `n/k`, then `e*k` is a divisor of `n` that is divisible by `k`.

Your code

```
ans = 1
for a in A:    // Here a is the prime factor and A[a] gives its power
    ans *= if( a is present in B ) ? 1 : A[a] + 1
print ans
```

calculates the number of divisors of `n` that are coprime to `k`.

Answer (score 1):

if the divisor is a prime number, then there is no other way than looping through all divisors. Otherwise [RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_%28algorithm%29) would not be a save crypto algorithem.